# Text automatically bold without the b tag being used

Tags: html, css

My text below is automatically bold when I have not used `<b>` or font weighting being heavy or anything like that I've tried using font weight lighter yet its still bold and there is no previous CSS that affects paragraphs which would make this happen I would like the text to be unbolded

[image]

```css
.Desc p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  margin: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.441);
}
```

```html
<div class="Desc">
  <h1>Welcome to Tea-rrific</h1>
  <p>Tea-rrific is a healthy alternative to other teas on the market. It contains antioxidants and vitamins which help boost your immune system and keep you healthy during cold and flu season. Tea-rrific tastes great without any added sugars or artificial
    sweeteners like many other teas on the market. And it's eco friendly because it uses biodegradable bags instead of plastic ones that pollute our oceans!<br>Tea-rrific is a small company based in the UK, creating small batch blends of high quality,
    ethical and sustainable whole leaf tea. We’re here to bring you tea that’s fun, functional and tasty!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to use font-weight: lighter !important; to see if anything changes.. because there’s the chance you have a rule somewhere else overriding that property because of higher specificity. Or maybe it’s because the font type bound to that font-family has only the bold. In that case you should change that. By the way you can inspect the element and see exactly which css properties get applied by your browser and in particular the loaded font type in the computed style section

Comment: The code you posted doesn't exhibit what you claim. We need a [mcve]

Comment: If you use `font-weight: lighter !important;` as Diego D suggests remember that it is _**temporary**_ to help you find the problem. You should never _need_ `!important` in production. Try using your browser tools to inspect that `.Desc p` element, it will show you all the styles that are applied to the element and you can find the rule where the bolding comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should sure that is font-family have light style like having link in head section or you can try

`font-weight:400;`